# Type returned by method based on constructor optional param

Tags: typescript

I have a class with constructor:

```js
class Example<T> {
    constructor(private elem: T, private array?: T[]) {}
}
```

and I want add method `some` with returned:

- `Promise<T>` if **not defined** param `array` in constructor
- `Promise<T[]>` if **defined** param `array` in constructor

How can I do this?

Actualy I have:

```js
class Example<T, S extends T[] | undefined> {
    constructor(private elem: T, private array?: S) {}

    some(): S extends undefined ? Promise<T> : Promise<S> {
        if(!this.array) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.elem);
        }

        return Promise.resolve(this.array);
    }
}

const a = new Example(1, undefined);
a.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number>

const b = new Example(1, [1, 2, 3]);
b.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number[]>

const c = new Example(1);
c.some(); // ✗ Return Promise<number> | Promise<number[]>, should return Promise<number>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need return type depends on the condition? Maybe you could be satisfied with statically defined union ```Promise<T> | Promise<T[]>```?

Comment: In this case, I think - yes. If we know that `some` method can return only one type from this union we should type it. It this way our types will be more correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the `extends` constraint from type parameter `S`
2. invert `S extends undefined ?` to `S extends T[] ?`

```
class Example<T, S> {
    constructor(private elem: T, private array?: S) {}

    some(): S extends T[] ? Promise<S> : Promise<T> {
        if (!this.array) {
            // @ts-ignore
            return Promise.resolve(this.elem);
        }
        // @ts-ignore
        return Promise.resolve(this.array);
    }
}

const a = new Example(1, undefined);
a.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number>

const b = new Example(1, [1, 2, 3]);
b.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number[]>

const c = new Example(1);
c.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTAPAFQDTQGUA+aAbwChorpgB7AOwgBcAnAV2CdpYAoUWAlgDcwTdNHQYkALmh5o-YaPFgWLMAE8A-LIIBKMgF9ylahFpJ0PPbonwx9ACYxsAbQC60LdAAKLCwIQWMTQsn4BQTgkFNSx0AIAZtA8AIRMABaBAHSq6hoGMXFFAPTF0AACTBAAtAIA5vTc6KZFsSzoTGws9L7+SIHoWe3mIEJWGdmS6Eh6ANwtccat0KUVVbUNTQttHV094f1BQ+gjYzwTEDlqmnMLxsbkdIxM0GDQALzQ9OgA7nCIqAwPAAjPg2E50AkBN9HLcwFlzJZrLMVmVAMjk0AASrtur0Ilh6GwkAAjdAsIgmJ7MaDEj5fX7-ZBoKyg6CuVkAJnwAGZ3LdiQiLFY5qjoBjsZ1cQcBphCSSyR4KY8GNTgHTvn8EEygcDbsBBUiRatxTj9n0ZXLSeTyEA)

Comment: Works good. But is not safe when you pass something not allowed as `S` type. 

`new Example(1, ["a", "b"]);`

This should return error. In this scenario [this solotion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446018/6623977) should be better.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found a solution:

```
class Example<T, S extends T[] | undefined = undefined> {
    constructor(private elem: T, private array?: S) {}

    some(): S extends undefined ? Promise<T> : Promise<S> {
        if(!this.array) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.elem) as any; // [1]
        }

        return Promise.resolve(this.array) as any; // [1]
    }
}

const a = new Example(1, undefined);
a.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number>

const b = new Example(1, [1, 2, 3]);
b.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number[]>

const c = new Example(1);
c.some(); // ✓ Return Promise<number>

const d = new Example(1, ["a", "b"]); // ✓ Should be error here
d.some();
```

*[1]* [Because of issues with conditional type returned type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) we need to use `as any` casting

More elegant should be [solution proposed by hackape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63444284/6623977) but it not cover `d` case where we expect error